# Create trigger that compares dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm very new to triggers and I can't seem to wrap my head around them. Let's assume I have two tables here:

```
CREATE TABLE Project 
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    startDate DATETIME,
    endDate DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE Work 
(
    date DATETIME,
    projectId INT
);
```

I insert some data:

```
INSERT INTO Project VALUES ('2017-04-18', '2017-05-01'); /*id = 1*/
INSERT INTO Work VALUES ('2017-04-17', 1);
```

Assuming there's only 1 project with `id = 1`, this should go well. However, it doesn't make much sense that my work starts the day before the project starts (not in this case). How would I create a trigger that basically says `date cannot be < startDate OR > endDate`?

Comment: You should handle business rules at the application layer, not at the database layer.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I know. This is not work related at all, and I would never do this in a real application.

Comment: Then... Use an `Instead of Insert Trigger` on the `Work` table.

Comment: @WEI_DBA If it was that easy, I wouldn't have asked on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_CheckInterval ON dbo.Work
   AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS 

IF NOT EXISTS (
    --if no records are returned then work date lies outside the project
    -- (start, end) interval
    SELECT 1
    FROM inserted AS i
    JOIN Project AS p 
       ON p.Id = i.projectId AND i.[date] BETWEEN p.startDate AND p.endDate 
)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Error: Your error message here.', 16, 1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END

GO
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot. Make a lot more sense now. I was missing the JOIN part completely.

Answer (score 1):

In your case instead of using trigger for these kind of checkings, I suggest to use a CHECK CONSTRAINT, something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_CheckWorkDate
(
    @WorkDate DateTime,
    @ProjectID INT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result BIT

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Project WHERE id = @ProjectID AND @WorkDate BETWEEN startdate AND endDate)
        SET @Result = 1
    ELSE
        SET @Result = 0

    RETURN @Result
END

GO

ALTER TABLE Work 
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_CheckWorkDate
    CHECK (dbo.ufn_CheckWorkDate(date, projectid) = 1)
```

Comment: Yes, using something else than a trigger (like a CONSTRAINT) is definitely much better. Thanks.